# How do I turn off automated testing in OWASP ZAP?

Tags: proxy, owasp, zap

I am trying to find out how to turn off the automated scanner in ZAP. I am not even sure if it is on.

How and where can I tell if the scanner is on? I just want it to be a pure proxy for the time being for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

ZAP does what you tell it to do.
It always performs passive scanning, but thats safe as it justs examines the requests and responses.
The active scanner performs the attacks, and that only runs when you tell it to.

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)

Answer (score 0):

When ZAP start the scanner is off.I take a screenshot so i can tell you the basic of ZAP.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLEnQ.jpg

1. select the profile for scan
2. Target to scan
3. Here is where the scanner put the results